# SQL dynamic pivoting or something else

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot

I have data in following format in an SQL table but need to present it differently.

| Name | Property | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | Gender | Male |
| Mark | Age | 45 |
| Mark | Weight | 167 |
| Chris | Gender | Male |
| Chris | height | 188 |

I'd very much like to present/select it like this, in an SQL query ideally:

| Name | Attributes |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | Gender = Male, Age=45, Weight=167 |
| Chris | Gender = Male, Height=188 |

I understand that dynamic pivoting may be an option but this is new to me. Is this correct and if so could anyone help create the query?
Any other suggestions would be welcome.

Many thanks.

I've tried UNIONS etc and this is the limit of my SQL knowledge.
I also have the option to use an ETL tool which may get the results but I'd like to just have an SQL query to run.

Comment: pivot transposes rows to columns, union is a vertical join you are looking for a combination of group_concat and concat grouping by name.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Property, ' = ', value SEPARATOR ', ') Attributes
FROM test
GROUP BY Name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R3YFqXEV)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the MSSQL version should anyone else need it:

SELECT Name, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(Property, '=', value), ' , ') as Attributes
FROM test
GROUP BY Name;

Comment: @Michael `SELECT Name, STRING_AGG(Property + ' = ' + Value, ', ') Attributes ...` https://dbfiddle.uk/1I69T3qG

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this query by using a join

```
SELECT t1.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(t1.Property, ' = ', t1.value SEPARATOR ', ') AS Attributes FROM test t1 JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM test) t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name GROUP BY t1.Name ORDER BY t1.Name DESC;
```